# Build Pjsip windows sdk/.net 6 target dll

Tags: c#, uwp, pjsip, dllexport, dll-injection

I am trying to create a pjsip dll and add it to an Uwp app. I have built a dll following [this](https://github.com/AaronReynoldsUK/PJSIP-PJSUA2-CSharp) (working fine for WPF). Which gives an error while adding dll to the Uwp project saying unsupported-frameworks don't match as uwp targets Windows SDK. Creating a .net standard 2.0 class library as a bridge also didn't work.
At first, I found this [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=msvc-170). But this also produces more errors.

Now, I want to create a dll for [Pjsip](https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject) and use it in my UWP app. I am badly in need of a solution for creating windows SDK using pjsip or a suggestion regarding workarounds to use the current win32 .net framework targetted dll in the uwp project.

Answer (score 0):

I have build pjsua2 dll and working fine using this [link](https://github.com/AaronReynoldsUK/PJSIP-PJSUA2-CSharp)

Comment: I have also created Dll using it. it's not usable in Uwp as I am not able to create 64bit/ .net 6/ uwp compatible dlls.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33176904)